# Is it possible to use one type in a multi-parameter function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Say I have the functions

```
add(x : number, y : number)
subtract(x : number, y : number)
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
type common = x : number, y : number

add<common>()
```

So I don't need to redefine the exact same things multiple times?

Comment: encapsulate the params into an object / type / interface and use that as the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlo's answer comes close, but I would use spread arguments and a named tuple:

```
type X_Y = [x: number, y: number];

function add(...args: X_Y) { return args[0] + args[1] };
function subtract(...args: X_Y) { return args[0] - args[1] };

add(1, 2);
subtract(1, 2);
```

If the result type is also always the same, you can consider creating one type for the whole operation:

```
type Op = (x: number, y: number) => number;

const add: Op = (x, y) => x + y
const substract: Op = (x, y) => x - y

add(1, 2)
subtract(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

a maybe not so elegant but:

```
type x_y = [number,number];
function add(i:x_y){
  return i[0]+i[1];
}
```